# Open Build System error, nothing provides dh-systemd(>=1.5) in Ubuntu 16.04 repository

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, packaging

I am trying to build a custom nginx package for Ubuntu 16.04 [[link to my project]](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:ssalil/nginx-dev). I created my gpg signed files to be uploaded using the command
Code:

```
debuild -S -sa -k'mygpgkey'
```

and uploaded

> nginx_1.8.0-1ppa~xenial.debian.tar.xz, nginx_1.8.0-1ppa~xenial.dsc,
>   nginx_1.8.0-1ppa~xenial_source.build,
>   nginx_1.8.0-1ppa~xenial_source.changes, nginx_1.8.0.orig.tar.xz

After the file upload repository of Ubuntu 16.04 displayed an error unreloved, "

> nothing provides dh-systemd(>=1.5)

". Later I included the
init-system-helper
package too in the

> .dsc

file but it didn't helped.

If anyone can please help me how can I get dh-systemd(>=1.5) installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 repository's test machine, then it would be a great help.

Thank you in advance.